# Does supplying Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS to getSharedPreferences() make the shared prefs thread safe?

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-safety, sharedpreferences

`SharedPreferences` aren't thread-safe, as is clearly said in the [Android docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

> Note: currently this class does not support use across multiple
>   processes. This will be added later.

However, I have an app that can fire six other `java.util.Threads` that `commit()` to the shared prefs and they may be fired concurrently (though it's unlikely that ALL of them will be). Which is why I always get a reference to my shared prefs from each of those threads this way:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(This.PREFS, Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);
```

I'm not sure, however, whether this makes the shared prefs reference thread-safe.

For example, when two of the six threads are fired and call on `commit()` at the same time, will one of the threads wait until the other one is done committing before it goes on to commit its own changes, or will it not commit altogether? The following line from the `commit()` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#commit%28%29) just sounds unclear to me:

> Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call commit wins.

What does "win" here mean? Why is it suddenly a "contest" between the two threads?

**ADD 3/11/2013:** Each of the threads modify a different entry in the shared prefs--they are not modifying the same key-value entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per this answer, shared preferences are thread-safe. What the Android docs said is that they aren't **multi-process safe**.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4695567/855680