# Loading a stored json from SharedPreferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, gson

**The problem**

This issue has been bugging me for quite some time. It is not very common, but it does happen from time to time. The problem is the following:

I save a bunch of user preferences in s Gson serialized object in SharedPreferences. This way, 
when I need the object I load it to memory doing only 1 call to storage. However, for some bizzare reason I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.a.b/com.a.b.SomeActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to parse type class com.a.b.storage.SomeClass$AppSettings with json: rialFinished":false,"lastOpenedAppId":0,"appVersion":35,"tutorialFinished":false}
```

As can be observed, the json was not loaded properly, it is an invalid json, so trying to parse it just throws an exception.

**Some Additional Facts**

- Every single exception thrown shows the exact same json parsing issue. For some reason this is **always** the string that is being loaded:

`rialFinished":false,"lastOpenedAppId":0,"appVersion":35,"tutorialFinished":false}`

- This is not a 'device specific issue' or at least I think so. Evidence: 
  [image]
  As you can see, its not specific to a device. I also know for a fact that it is not specific to an android version either, we have this crashed logged from Android `2.3.6`, `4.0.3`, `4.1.1`, `4.1.2`, `4.0.4`
- The class that is serialized is

  ```
  class AppSettings {

  private boolean tutorialFinished;
  private boolean googleAuthTutorialFinished;
  private int appVersion;
  private int lastOpenedAppId;

  public AppSettings() {
      tutorialFinished = false;
      appVersion = NO_STORED_VERSION;
      googleAuthTutorialFinished = false;
  }

  public boolean isTutorialFinished() {
      return tutorialFinished;
  }

  public void setTutorialFinished(boolean tutorialFinished) {
      this.tutorialFinished = tutorialFinished;
  }

  public void setAppVerions(int appVerions) {
      this.appVersion = appVerions;
  }

  public void setGoogleAuthTutorialFinished(boolean googleAuthTutorialFinished) {
      this.googleAuthTutorialFinished = googleAuthTutorialFinished;
  }

  /**
   *
   * @return the stored app version or {@link AppSettingsStorage#NO_STORED_VERSION} if none was found
   */
  public int getAppVerions() {
      return appVersion;
  }

  public boolean isGoogleAuthTutorialFinished() {
      return googleAuthTutorialFinished;
  }

  public int getLastOpenedAppId() {
      return lastOpenedAppId;
  }

  public void setLastOpenedAppId(int lastOpenedAppId) {
      this.lastOpenedAppId = lastOpenedAppId;
  }

  }
  ```
- the method used to load the json is:

  ```
      private T fromJson(String json) {
              try {
                  return gson.fromJson(json, type);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  throw new RuntimeException("unable to parse type " + type + " with json: " + json);
              }
          }
  ```

**Possible reasons:**

- https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14359. This issue states that some Android devices just don't work well with the SharedPreferences. Although I'm sure that specific issue is not the case here, I wonder if it has something to do.
- Maybe there is some odd process-safety issue at hand here. ([Shared Preferences And Thread/Process safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693387/sharedpreferences-and-thread-safety))
- AppSettings is an inner class. Could this affect Gson serialization somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a double quote?

```
unable to parse type class com.a.b.storage.SomeClass$AppSettings with json: 

rialFinished":false,"lastOpenedAppId":0,"appVersion":35,"tutorialFinished":false}
```

should that be:

```
unable to parse type class com.a.b.storage.SomeClass$AppSettings with json: 

"rialFinished":false,"lastOpenedAppId":0,"appVersion":35,"tutorialFinished":false}
```

Comment: I'm not missing a double quote, that is exactly the problem. When Gson serializes the AppSetting object, the json string which should be a valid json, is being loaded as an invalid json. Do you see the problem?

Comment: Sorry. I disagree.  The string you say in json is simply not properly formatted JSON the way you have it in this post.