# Scope and type of Application Context to use for multi thread activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-context

I have an activity where I have two threads running off the Main thread. Both of access network and Shared Preferences. And the context I use for them is application context. So, is it recommended to use a single application context instance (maybe static?), member of the main activity, initialized in onCreate; for accessing, editing Shared Preferences from Multiple threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be no memory leak with the application context, so it can be safely stored in a static member. Be mindful, however, that this context should not be used to create `View` instances (but it's OK for `SharedPreferences`).

If you launch the threads from an `Activity` instance, you can simply use `getApplicationContext()`.

Another common way is to subclass `Application`, then store the reference to the object in a static field. For example:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application
{
    static sApplication;

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate();
        sApplication = this;
    }

    public static Context getAppContext()
    {
        return sApplication.getApplicationContext();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Ok. I guess then using `getApplicationContext()` would be better. Also, if I make the `SharedPreference` object an instance of activity and use it across threads, would that be better?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` implementation is thread-safe (at least according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4695567/82788) so that would work.