# Synchronization issue SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sharedpreferences

I have a public static method in one of my classes for my app which saves a number to SharedPreferences after incrementing it. For example if the preference value is a long equal to 1, the method will read the preference of 1 into a long variable, then increment it to 2, and put that long back into the preference.

Do I ever have to worry about synchronization issues? At first I don't think so, because my application is not multithreaded right? It uses Android Services, but I think that is only single threaded as well.

Comment: where and how are you accessing preferences values. Do you have a preference listener implemented?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693387/sharedpreferences-and-thread-safety

Comment: I'm accessing it from a public static method of a subclass of the Service class. The method has an input parameter of Context and I use Context.getSharedPreferences to access the Preference and SharedPreferences.Editor.putLong to write to the Preference.

Answer (score 7):

Java has a solution for the `Synchronization` by simply implement the method in a `synchronized` structure as the following"

```
public synchronized void modifyPreferences(long input)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

The `SharefPreferences` [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply()) says about using `apply()` vs `commit()` for saving your edits:

> Using apply(), Note that when two editors are modifying preferences at the same time, the last one to call apply wins.
>
> Unlike commit(), which writes its preferences out to persistent storage synchronously, apply() commits its changes to the in-memory SharedPreferences immediately but starts an asynchronous commit to disk and you won't be notified of any failures. If another editor on this SharedPreferences does a regular commit() while a apply() is still outstanding, the commit() will block until all async commits are completed as well as the commit itself.

I hope this helps.