# unable to read data form sharedpreference variable

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

Shared Preferences are created as follows:

```
edt = sp.edit();
edt.putString("token_value", pojo.getKey());
edt.commit();
```

and I want to use this values in another class like this:

```
String key = sp.getString("token_value", "");
```

at this point I got an error like this:

`Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String android.content.SharedPreferences.getString(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

Please give me your valuable suggestions and thanks in advance...

Comment: please provide the whole method

Comment: Hello sir this is complete method
public static String PREF_NAME = "Login";
    public static int PRIVATE_MODE=0;
SharedPreferences sp;
    SharedPreferences.Editor edt;
sp=getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
            edt=sp.edit();
            edt.putString("token_value",pojo.getKey());

Comment: This code is not sufficient to understand the exact problem, Please provide the detailed code.

Comment: Did you placed and accessed preferences in same thread ?
If you are putting and accessing the preferences in different process, you might face issues..

Comment: More details can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4695567/3796784

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer or post your own solution. It may be helpful for other with the same question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Before retrieving the preferences did you initialize the `sp` object?

```
SharedPreferences sp = yourActivity.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String key = sp.getString("token_value", "");
```

The exception clearly states that your `sp` variable is a null reference and not pointing to any object.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are passing null while getting a value. Change it to

```
String key = sp.getString("token_value", null);
```

like this and you will get the value.

Comment: Getting `""` is totally fine. That's the default string (empty) he will get if the variable does not exist on the `SharedPreferences`. Not null.

Answer (score 0):

You `SharedPreferences` variable `sp` is declared but not initialised. Add this to your code:

```
SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(YourActivity.this);
String key = sp.getString("token_value","");
```

Answer (score 0):

To save variable at `SharedPreferences`

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
// make sure pojo.getKey() return value not null prefer make check here 
//if(pojo.getKey() != null)
editor.putString("token_value",pojo.getKey());
editor.apply();
```

retrieve any where you want

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String name = preferences.getString("token_value", "");
```

do what ever you want with your string

Comment: sorry to say still I got same error sir like this -----------
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference

Comment: where you call getString method , activity , fragment , adapter

Comment: any way this issue mean you pass wrong context , so replace this with Activity.this , or right context

Comment: please check this one sir 
public class ConfigTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,JSONObject> {
        ConfigCallback callback;
        private String emailId;
        Context con;
        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(con);
        String name = sp.getString("token_value", "");
    
        public ConfigTask(ConfigCallback callback, String emailId) {
            Log.d("++++++++++++++","+++++++++++"+ sp.getString("token_value",""));
            this.callback = callback;
            this.emailId = emailId;
        }